# Creating (large) object in void function failing for unknown reasons

Tags: c++

I have been puzzled by my program's behavior with certain object allocations for a little while now.

My `main()` function runs like so:

```
const int numOpts = 3;
string opts[numOpts] = { "Play", "Settings", "Quit" };
                        // 0       1           2
for (;;)
{
    int choice = input(numOpts); // returns 0, 1, or 2
    if (choice == 0)
    {
        Game b; // 9
        b.start(); // 10
    }
    else if (choice == 1)
        settings(); // edits global variables
    else
        break;
}
```

However, when I try to put lines 9 and 10 (`Game b; b.start();`) in their own `void` function,

```
static void startGame();

int main()
{
    ...
    if (choice == 0)
        startGame();
    ...
}

static void startGame()
{
    Game b;
    b.start();
}
```

the program soon crashes (segmentation fault) after one iteration of the `for (;;)` loop. In Xcode, `main()` seems to forget all of its variables after the call to `startGame()`. Similarly,

```
static void startGame()
{
    Game* b = new Game;
    b->start();
    delete b;
}
```

also fails: however not on my own OS (OS X), but on a Linux machine. The output for this is failure looks like this: `*** glibc detected *** ./Game: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001b41d60 *** ...`.

Are these problems related? I suspect that stack data for `main()` is somehow being freed, but if so, why does the first implementation work, but not the next two?

Comment: The function `startGame` is clearly not the problem and the stack of `main` does not get freed until the application terminates. There must be some bug in your code (most likely related to pointers and memory allocations) that only surfaces in some situations.

Comment: Unless your game is very very short you probably don't want it to go out of scope or delete it immediately after creating it.

Comment: @MartinLiversage This sounds about right.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The `start()` function executes the entirety of the Game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Game class writes to memory that is outside of its control, thus corrupting the heap or stack, depending on where you allocate it. Look for buffer overruns in "Game".